Internals of worker/executor usage during coalesce/repartition
Lets say we have spark cluster with below configuration.

1 Driver and 1000 workers
Each worker has 5 executer
Each executer has 4 core

Ho does coalesce/repartition works, when we perform coalesce (50) or repartition(50)

does Spark creates 50 partition each on a separate worker ie. it uses 50 workers or
many partition can be in single worker for ex: In above case since there are 5 executor/worker, so each worker will have 5 partition ie 1 partition/executor, so spark uses only 10 workers?



It creates 50 partitions in total across the whole cluster.
The question is not absolutely clear but basically partitions are not tied to workers. They can be shuffled and it all depends on the nature of your operations with your data. They also can be distributed across the workers unevenly so e.g. 1 worker will have 20 partitions, 30 more workers will have 1 partition each and other 969 will idle while the first one will have to grind 20 of them.


for #2, on what basis Spark decides whether partitions should be distributed across all nodes or few? could you please provide few example if possible. thank you.

well it's a complex topic and depends on the exact scenarios. In case when you just do repartition you can only control how partitions are formed by specifying columns to repartition on but you can't control where those partitions go. Spark tries to distribute it evenly but it all depends on the partitions_num/executor_num ratio, data size - if it fits into one or few executors etc.
